# Mapear tabelas associativas no Entity

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

Isso já aconteceu. Quando eu uso uma tabela associativa no Entity, essas tabelas geralmente não possuem PK. Quando isso ocorre, não consigo mapeá-las. Como posso mapear esse tipo de tabela?

Comment: Como assim, você está criando Tabela sem PK, em banco de dados relacional? Qual a logica em fazer isso? E lembrando a PK mapeada no ORM, não precisa necessariamente ser uma PK na base de dados, só deve ser um identificador único. Apesar de não ser uma boa pratica. Explique melhor seu contexto de criar uma tabela dessa forma?

Comment: Em realidade são tabelas associativas, ou seja, tabelas intermediárias quando se tem N2N. Normalmente não se tem PK, apenas FK's nessas tabelas e meu Entity não mapeou.

Comment: Faltou duas tabelas. Uma delas, que eu chamo de Usuario_Cargo, ela possui duas FK's, que são: IDUsuario e IDCargo, apenas esses dois campos. Essa tabela não foi mapeada.

Comment: Na verdade nesse seu caso, você criou uma relação NxN entre Usuário e Cargo certo? Onde um Usuário poder ter vários cargos e o mesmo cargo pode pertencer a vários Usuários. OK? Então se não há nada a ser acrescentado na relação Cargo X Usuário, não é necessário mapear explicitamente essa relação, pois o próprio Usuário e Cargo já informam o que é necessário para que o ORM já reconheça essa tabela como uma relação entre as duas. Mas se você realmente desejar mapear essa tabela de relacionamento por qualquer motivo, você deve considerar o uso de Chave Composta, que seria o IDUsuario e o IDCargo.

Comment: Você precisa ter um PK para mapear, mesmo porque, é boa prática de Banco de Dados ter uma PK para todas as tabelas, até as tabelas associativas - ela pode ser necessária por agilidade.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mapeie manual. Por exemplo:

```
public class Usuario 
{
    [Key]
    public int UsuarioId {get;set;}

    [Required]
    public String Nome {get;set;}
    ...
    public virtual ICollection<UsuarioCargo> UsuarioCargos {get;set;}
}

public class Cargo 
{
    [Key]
    public int CargoId {get;set;}

    [Required]
    public String Nome {get;set;}
    ...
    public virtual ICollection<UsuarioCargo> UsuarioCargos {get;set;}
}

public class UsuarioCargo
{
    [Key]
    public int UsuarioCargoId { get; set; }
    [Index("IUQ_UsuarioCargo_UsuarioId_CargoId", IsUnique = true, Order = 1)]
    public int UsuarioId { get; set; }
    [Index("IUQ_UsuarioCargo_UsuarioId_CargoId", IsUnique = true, Order = 2)]
    public int CargoId  { get; set; }

    public virtual Usuario Usuario {get;set;}
    public virtual Cargo Cargo {get;set;}
}
```

Isto retira a incerteza do Entity Framework estar mapeando errado seu esquema de `Models`.

[`[Index]`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.schema.indexattribute(v=vs.113).aspx), introduzido nesta forma a partir do Entity Framework 6.1.0, garante a unicidade do registro associativo. Validações adicionais podem ser necessárias na aplicação para evitar erros estranhos de duplicidade de chave para o usuário.