# Vários Livros para Autor

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc

Recentemente, fiz uma pergunta sobre o meu problema, mas ficou meio difícil de entender, aqui vou tentar resumir o meu problema.

Estou usando ASP.NET MVC.

Tenho 2 tabelas: `Autores` e `Livros`, onde 1 `Autor` tem muitos `Livros`.

Quando for criar o `Autor` e quiser adicionar mais um `Livro`, tenho um botão que cria meus campos via `jQuery`, so que quando eu for salvar, o meu `Controller` pega apenas o 1º nome, os demais nomes que eu adicionei por `jQuery` não são adicionados corretamente.

Então vamos a tela para cadastrar autor (exemplo):

```
     <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-4">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Nome)
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Nome)
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-4">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.NomeLivro)
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.NomeLivro)
    </div>

    //DIV PARA RECEBER OS NOVOS CAMPOS
    <div id="divAddLivro"></div>
```

Aí tenho meu botão para a chamada jQuery:

```
    <button id="btnAddLivro">Adicionar Livro</button>
```

meu `jQuery`:

```
            $("#btnAddLivro").click(function () {
            $("#divAddLivro").append(''+
                        '<div class="col-xs-12 col-md-4">'+
                        '    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Nome)'+
                        '    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Nome)'+
                        '</div>'+
                        '<div class="col-xs-12 col-md-4">'+
                            '    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.NomeLivro)'+
                            '    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.NomeLivro)'+
                        '</div>' +
                '</div>');
            });
```

**MODEL AUTOR**

```
public class Autor
{
    [Key]
    public int IdAutor { get; set; }

    public string Nome { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Livro> Livros{ get; set; }

}
```

**MODEL LIVRO**

```
public class Livro
{
    [Key]
    public int IdLivro { get; set; }

    public string Nome { get; set; }

    public int IdAutor { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Autor> Autores { get; set; }

}
```

Comment: O que você está utilizando para a parte web?  Asp.net MVC, WebForms, Angular, etc, etc, etc... Poderia postar o código de como está fazendo isso?

Comment: ok @Randrade vou especificar

Comment: @Randrade alterei a pergunta, obrigado

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Desta forma que você está fazendo não irá funcionar mesmo. Você está manipulando apenas `html`, mas o servidor não entende que você está passando uma lista de livros para o `controller`.

Para isso, o mais recomendado é utilizar o pacote [BeginCollectionItem](https://www.nuget.org/packages/BeginCollectionItem/).

Para utilizar, instale o memso pelo NuGet com o este comando:

> Install-Package BeginCollectionItem

Feito isso, vamos as modificações em seu projeto.

Você não postou os seus Models, então irei supor que você já possui a lista de Autores para cada livro.

Em seu `controller` precisamos criar uma `Action` para retornar um novo autor. Para isso, adicione essa `Action` em seu controller Autores.

```
 public ActionResult GetNewAutor()
    {
        var autor = new Autor()

        return PartialView("_Autor", autor );
    }
```

Nesta `Action` estamos criando um novo autor e retornando uma `PartialView` com o mesmo. Sua `PartialView` será a mesma coisa que o código que você utilizou no `append`, em sua pergunta. Ficará assim:

```
@model Projeto.Autor//Altere isso

@using (Html.BeginCollectionItem("Livros"))//O nome da sua lista
{
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-4">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Nome)
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Nome)
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-4">
      @Html.LabelFor(model => model.NomeLivro)
      @Html.EditorFor(model => model.NomeLivro)
    </div>
}
```

O nome Autores desta parte `@using (Html.BeginCollectionItem("Livros"))` deve ser o mesmo nome da virtual `public virtual ICollection<Livros> Livros{get;set;}` em seu Model Autores.

Em sua `view`, vamos alterar a forma de "duplicar" o campo, utilizando uma requisição `ajax` para o `controller`.

```
<script>
    $('#btnAddLivro').click(function () {
        $.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Action("GetNewAutor", "Autores")',
            type: 'POST',
            success: function (data) {
                $('#new-autor').append(data);
            }
        });
    });

</script>
```

Nesta requisição estamos adicionando um outro autor em seu código (realizando a requisição no `controller`).

Note que nesta parte `$('#new-autor').append(data);` estamos fazendo o `append()` da `PartialView()` para a `div` com o `id="new-autor"`. Então basta criar uma `div` vazia com esse id onde quer que os inputs sejam adicionados, desta forma:

```
<div id="new-autor"></div>
```

Fazendo isso, ao mandar salvar, você terá uma lista de autores em seu `Model`.

Comment: Caso não entenda, forneça as informações de seu `cotnroller` e `Models` que adéquo a resposta para você.

Comment: obrigado pela sua resposta, vou tentar aqui, so um momento

Comment: desculpe a demora pelo retorno, tive alguns problemas aqui, a lista de Autores para cada livro, eu coloco ela no model do Livro ou do Autor ?

Comment: vc tem skype para nos falarmos melhor?

Comment: No seu caso, um autor possui muitos livros, então o Model Autor terá uma lista de `ICollection` de livros.

Comment: vou editar minha pergunta com os models, aguardo

Comment: consegui aqui, obrigado pela sua resposta

Comment: @Furlan Estava montando um exemplo para você, mas que bom que conseguiu. Acho que você terá alguns problemas com esse relacionamento (N : N), aconselharia fazer uma [tabela associativa](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/29191/20615), acho que evitaria transtornos, mas isso é outra questão.

Comment: é eu ja vi esse problema. eu tive que inverter meu exemplo, quando eu for cadastrar o livro, eu adiciono os autores, ai ele cria 2 vezes. Se vc quiser colocar o exemplo, eu fico grato, pode me ajudar la pra frente, obrigado desde já